# Streaming my application data to jKool cloud using REST API fails

Tags: ibm-cloud, jkoolcloud

I have created jKool service in IBM Bluemix, I have created an account in jKool cloud. My user name is parimargu in the jKool cloud.

When I am trying to stream my data into jKool cloud using REST API is failing with my token.

REST Endpoint, I am using is: http://data.jkoolcloud.com:6580/JESL/event

I have created the event and making a post request:

```
String jKoolToken = "<my jkool cloud token>";
// Stream the event (token is the token that was assigned to you
// when you purchased jKool.
response = target.path("event").request()
.header("token", jKoolToken)
.post(Entity.entity(serialize(event), "application/json"));
response.close();
```

The error I am getting is:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request

I am stuck here, could someone guide me through this? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This exception means you have a problem with your build environment or missing jar files. Verify you have all required jar files in class path.